# The params can't pass to vuex's update method

Tags: vue.js, vuex

in store.js:

```
const actions { 
...   
update_search_condition_params_delete_params({commit}, {delete_search_condition_params}){     
  console.log("delete_search_condition_params: = ", 
  delete_search_condition_params)  // Line 101     
  commit('mutations_search_condition_params_delete_params', delete_search_condition_params)   }
}
```

when I dispatch the update method of store in my code,

```
console.log("sc_style: ", this.sc_style)  // there have a item  
this.$store.dispatch('update_search_condition_params_delete_params', this.sc_style)
```

but when I test it I get error:

[image]

you see the `delete_search_condition_params = undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
const actions {
  update_search_condition_params_delete_params(vuexContext, delete_search_condition_params) {      
     vuexContext.commit('mutations_search_condition_params_delete_params', delete_search_condition_params) 
  }
}
```